# pointer parameter passed by reference in a function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a class template which has a member variable `std::vector<T> buffer` and a member function `setData`, among others.

```
template <class T>
void ArrayT<T>::setData(const std::vector<T> * & data_ptr) {    
    buffer.assign(data_ptr->begin(), data_ptr->end());
}
```

I want `setData` to perform a deep copy of the data passed as its argument. As you can see, the argument is of type `* &`, which if I understand well is a pointer parameter passed by reference.

When I write:

```
vector<float> vec(3, 1.0);
vector<float>* vec2 = &vec;
A obj();
obj.setData(vec2);
```

I get an error:

> E0434 a reference of type "const std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>> *&" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>> *"

Could someone please explain how to fix this?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Plenty of reasons to do that. None of them are evident here though.

Answer (score 1):

The input parameter of `setData()` is a reference to a non-const pointer to a **const** `std::vector`. But the `std::vector` object you are pointing at is not `const`.

There is no reason to use a pointer at all in this situation. Change `setData()` to take the `std::vector` by const reference instead:

```
template <class T>
void ArrayT<T>::setData(const std::vector<T> &data)
{
    buffer.assign(data.begin(), data.end());
    // or simply: buffer = data;
}
```

```
vector<float> vec(3, 1.0);
Array<float> obj;
obj.setData(vec);
```

That being said, if you want to keep the pointer, you need to drop the `const`:

```
template <class T>
void ArrayT<T>::setData(std::vector<T> * data_ptr)
{
    buffer.assign(data_ptr->begin(), data_ptr->end());
    // or simply: buffer = *data_ptr;
}
```

Or at least move the `const` after the `*` to make the pointer itself `const` rather than the object it is pointing at:

```
template <class T>
void ArrayT<T>::setData(std::vector<T> * const data_ptr)
{
    buffer.assign(data_ptr->begin(), data_ptr->end());
    // or simply: buffer = *data_ptr;
}
```

Either way, notice I removed the reference.  There is no good reason to pass a pointer by reference when you are not modifying what the pointer is pointing at.  Pass the pointer by value instead.

Comment: Is there a solution in the case i keep the pointer in the argument type? Or is it wrong and i should definitely remove it?

Comment: Thank you! I think i understand better now